# jQuery - selector. Select child div and find background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, selector

Question i asked earlier along the same lines - [jQuery - Selecting a child div background image and amending it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923849/jquery-selecting-a-child-div-background-image-and-amending-it). Definitely helped but im trying to simplify it down to this selector if possible.

Im looking for a way to select a child div with a class of "portlet-arrow" and get the current background-image url.

So what i need is this.

On click of the div with id "what is crm head" i need a selector that can find the child div with a class of portlet arrow and get the current background image url.

The closest i have got is this:

```
$( ".portlet-header" ).click(function() {
    var currValue = $(this).children(".portlet-arrow").css("background-image")
});
```

Here is my current html

```
<div class="portlet" id="what-is-crm">
    <div class="portlet-header header-styling" id="what-is-crm-head">
        <div class="portlet-arrow red-arrow-visible"></div>
            What is CRM?
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-content">
        Mauris pretium vehicula suscipit. Donec tincidunt
        volutpat risus, non pulvinar nunc feugiat ac.
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="#">View More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing a $
$( ".portlet-header" ).click(function() {
    var currValue = $(this).children(".portlet-arrow").css("background-image")
});

Comment: Added that in to the question, just going to retest my code and see what it pulls up

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/S75fd/) with the added `$`.

Comment: How to debug javascript with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/whatisfirebug) or [Chrome](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/), you'll save yourself precious time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is you are missing the $ when creating a JQuery object for "this"...

```
var currValue = $(this).children(".portlet-arrow").css("background-image");
```

Without the $ sign you will not create a JQuery object, and thus the children function will not be a valid call

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/X4Arp/)

Comment: Absolutely right there. Thanks for the help there. Ill give you the answer when the timer has run out

Answer (score 1):

It should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/6WJEN/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".portlet-header" ).click(function() {
    var currValue = $(this).children(".portlet-arrow").css("background-image");
    alert(currValue);
});
});
```